# nrow(matrix) function

Tags: r, statistics

I have assignment using R and have a little problem. In the assignment several matrices have to be generated with random number of rows and later used for various calculations. Everything works perfect, unless number of rows is 1.

In the calculations I use nrow(matrix) in different ways, for example `if (i <= nrow(matrix) ) {action}` and also statements like `matrix[,4]` and so on.

So in case number of rows is 1 (I know it is actually vector) R give errors, definitely because nrow(1-dimensional matrix)=NULL. Is there simple way to deal with this? Otherwise probably whole code have to be rewritten, but I'm very short in time :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's call your vector `x`. Try using `matrix(x)` or `t(matrix(x))` to convert it into a proper (2D) matrix.

Answer (score 7):

It is not that single-row/col matrices in R have `ncol`/`nrow` set to `NULL` -- in R everything is a 1D vector which can behave like matrix (i.e. show as a matrix, accept matrix indexing, etc.) when it has a `dim` attribute set. It seems otherwise because simple indexing a matrix to a single row or column *drops* `dim` and leaves the data in its default (1D vector) state.

Thus you can accomplish your goal either by directly recreating `dim` attribute of a vector (say it is called x):

```
dim(x)<-c(length(x),1)
x #Now a single column matrix

dim(x)<-c(1,length(x))
x #Now a single row matrix
```

OR by preventing `[]` operator from dropping `dim` by adding `drop=FALSE` argument:

```
x<-matrix(1:12,3,4)
x                #OK, matrix
x[,3]            #Boo, vector
x[,3,drop=FALSE] #Matrixicity saved!
```